# getTime is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript

I set `date_work` to Date data type. But when I check the data type using the command  `console.log(typeof master.date_work)` it appears for some reason the type of `string`. And because of this, when I use the `getTime()` function such an error occurs. How can I change the string data type to Date?

> TypeError: master.date_work.getTime is not a function

**Model:**

```
export interface Masters {
    master_id?: string,
    full_name: string,
    comment: string,
    date_work: Date,
    teams_id: string
}
```

**ts:**

```
reports: Rep4Hours[]
masters: Masters[]
teams: Teams[]
filteredTeams = []
filteredMasters = []

onSelectedReport(reportId) {
  this.selectedReport = this.reports.find(
    el => {
      return el.report_id === reportId
    }
  )

  if (this.teamsService) {
    this.teamsService.fetch().subscribe(
      team => {
        this.teams = team
        this.filteredTeams = this.teams.filter(
          (team) => team.team_id == this.selectedReport.teams_id
        )
        if (this.mastersService) {
          this.mastersService.fetch().subscribe(
            master => {
              this.filteredMasters = []
              this.masters = master
              for(let team of this.filteredTeams){
                for(let master of this.masters){
                  if(master.teams_id == team.team_id){
                    if (Math.max(...this.masters.map(master => master.date_work.getTime()))) {
                      if (master.date_work <= this.selectedReport.report_date) {
                        this.filteredMasters.push(master)
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          )
        }
      }
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Your date is not a Date object and not of type Date. Defining a type of a property doesn't guarantee the same type to be assigned. Typescript will only check for compile time validations, what you assign at runtime is not validated. You can either convert all the `date_work` to date Object using `new Date(yourProp.date_work)`, or convert it only at the place you do the comparison

Comment: Please check  master.date_work is not null

Comment: Just try loggin `this.masters` after the `this.masters = master;` line and check to see what is being logged on to the console.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting a string to a date in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619202/converting-a-string-to-a-date-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Complementaring xyz's answer, your service can convert your "data_work" in Date Object of javaScript. (I supouse you received the date in string format)

```
//Your masterService
fetch()
{
     return this.httpClient.get(...)
     .pipe(map(x=>
           {...x,  //all the properties of "x"
            date_work:new Date(x.date_work)  //but date_work, convert to Date object 
           }
     ))
}
```

Answer (score -1):

your data `date_work` is not in `Date` format. Typescript cannot give guarantee for incoming service object.

there are inconsistencies between your model and service return object. When you map your class to returning object typescript annotates `date_work` as Date  however in actual data it is not.